# Higher-order functions and ST

Tags: haskell

I'm playing with http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vault/0.2.0.0/doc/html/Data-Vault-ST.html and want to write functions like the following:

```
onVault  f = runST (f <$> Vault.newKey)
onVault2 f = runST (f <$> Vault.newKey <*> Vault.newKey)
```

etc.  If I replace these functions with ones that take no arguments and call a particular function instead of f, it works, but these higher-order functions will not type check.

What is going on and can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give `onVault` and `onVault2` [rank 2 types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Rank-N_types).

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-} -- RankNTypes would also work

onVault :: (forall s. Key s a -> b) -> b
onVault2 :: (forall s. Key s a -> Key s b -> c) -> c
```

This is because `runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a` requires that the passed action is polymorphic in the state thread parameter `s`, which is a type-level trick used to guarantee purity. See [the ST monad article on HaskellWiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad/ST) for details.

Comment: Hmm... I was afraid it might be something like that.  It seems that if I let the result be in `ST` and then call `runST` later on when I use the value, that also works.

Comment: @singpolyma: Yes, because that puts the (implicit) forall quantifier on `s` at the outermost level, which makes it a normal rank 1 type which can be inferred and doesn't require extensions.