# Adding "runST" to value of type "ST s a" makes it stop typechecking

Tags: haskell, types, state, monads

I have the following function:

```
foo :: (GMV.MVector v a) => Matrix v (PrimState (ST s)) a -> (Int, Int) -> ST s a
foo mat (x, y) = get (Vec x y 0) mat
```

It returns `ST s a`, but I want it to return just `a`. Notice that `runST` has type:

```
runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a
```

So I replaced my function definition to:

```
foo :: (GMV.MVector v a) => Matrix v (PrimState (ST s)) a -> (Int, Int) -> a
foo mat (x, y) = runST (get (Vec x y 0) mat)
```

Expected it to work, but I got the following error:

```
Main.hs:16:41:
    Could not deduce (s1 ~ s)
    from the context (GMV.MVector v a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 foo :: GMV.MVector v a =>
                        Matrix v (PrimState (ST s)) a -> (Int, Int) -> a
      at Main.hs:15:8-76
      ‘s1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
           a type expected by the context: ST s1 a at Main.hs:16:18
      ‘s’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            foo :: GMV.MVector v a =>
                   Matrix v (PrimState (ST s)) a -> (Int, Int) -> a
          at Main.hs:15:8
    Expected type: Matrix v (PrimState (ST s1)) a
      Actual type: Matrix v (PrimState (ST s)) a
    Relevant bindings include
      mat :: Matrix v (PrimState (ST s)) a (bound at Main.hs:16:5)
      foo :: Matrix v (PrimState (ST s)) a -> (Int, Int) -> a
        (bound at Main.hs:16:1)
    In the second argument of ‘get’, namely ‘mat’
    In the first argument of ‘runST’, namely ‘(get (Vec x y 0) mat)’
```

If I understand it, it is trying to equate the "s" from inside runST's type, with the "s" from "foo"'s type? How to I get around that?

Comment: Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433667/higher-order-functions-and-st

Comment: Uhm... yes... it is similar. Indeed, adding a "forall s" **wrapped in a parenthesis with the first argument** like that suggested worked. I'll be honest and admit I have no clue what I have just done.

Comment: It means that the first argument of `foo` must be independent of `s`, which means more-or-less that it doesn't depend on any external state.